# How can I convert dropdown list into checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, datatables

My project requires users to select Name first before selecting any other dropdown. To accomplish this, I want to convert the first dropdown (Name) into checkboxes (keeping the same filtering). Is it possible to convert only the Name column dropdown into checkboxes.

Here is the code I am working on. https://jsfiddle.net/mL9f58wg/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#table-wrap').hide();
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({

    responsive: true,
mark: true,
stateSave: false,
    searching: true
  });

  buildSelect(table);
  $('#table-filter').on('change', function () {
    // show the tbody when the user clicks on a filter option
$('#table-wrap').show();
    table.columns.adjust();

    table.search(this.value).draw();
  });

 
  table.on('draw', function() {
    buildSelect(table);
  });
  $('#test').on('click', function() {
    table.search('').columns().search('').draw();
    $('#table-wrap').hide();
  });
});

function buildSelect(table) {
  var counter = 0;
  table.columns([0, 1, 2]).every(function() {
    var column = table.column(this, {
      search: 'applied'
    });
    counter++;
    var select = $('<select id="dd' + counter + '"><option value="">Select</option></select>')
      .appendTo($('#dropdown' + counter).empty())
      .on('change', function() {
        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
          $(this).val()
        );

        column
          .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
          .draw();
      });

    column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>');

    });

    // The rebuild will clear the exisiting select, so it needs to be repopulated
    var currSearch = column.search();
    if (currSearch) {
           // Use RegEx to find the selected value from the unique values of the column.
      // This will use the Regular Expression returned from column.search to find the first matching item in column.data().unique
      select.val(column.data().unique().toArray().find((e) => e.match(new RegExp(currSearch))));
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
  </head>
<div class="searchbox" select id="table-filter">
<p><label for="dd1">Name:</label> <span id="dropdown1" input type="checkbox">
  </span>
</p>

<p><label for="dd2">Postion:</label> <span id="dropdown2">
  </span>
</p>

<p><label for="dd3">Office:</label> <span id="dropdown3">
</span>
</p>
  <button type="button"  id="test">Clear Filters</button>
</div>
  <div id="table-wrap">
  <table id="example" class="cell-border row-border stripe dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" role="grid" style=" width: 100%; padding-top: 10px;"><thead>
<tr>

<th>&#160;</th>
<th>&#160;</th>
<th>&#160;</th>
<th colspan="3" style=" text-align: center;">Information</th>
</tr>


          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>ID.AI</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Garrett -2</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ashton.1 -2</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
          </tr>
          
            
          </tr></tbody></table>
</div>
```

Comment: Using checkboxes is the wrong model, unless you intend that someone can select more than one name. You could also accomplish your goal (force Name to be selected first) without changing it from a drop-down to a set of checkboxes/radio-buttons.  Start with the other drop-downs disabled and only enable them after a selection is made from the Name - just check for `name.value.length > 0`

Comment: Thankyou, its a great idea!! How do I disable other drop-downs? Can you please provide an example.

Comment: When you build your `<select>` in `buildSelect(table)` you create it using `var select = $('<select id="dd' + counter + '">...` — you can add the _disabled_ attribute to that like `<select id="dd' + counter + '" disabled>` ... Now that's going to make _all_ selects disabled, including the _Name_, so you would have to do something like `document.getElementById('dd1').removeAttribute('disabled')` to re-enable Name.  That's also how you would enable the other drop-downs when a name gets selected.

Comment: Thankyou, can you please provide an example if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#table-wrap').hide();
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    mark: true,
    stateSave: false,
    searching: true
  });

  buildCheckboxes(table); // Use buildCheckboxes instead of buildSelect
  $('#table-filter').on('change', function () {
    // show the tbody when the user clicks on a filter option
    $('#table-wrap').show();
    table.columns.adjust();
    table.search(this.value).draw();
  });

  table.on('draw', function() {
    buildCheckboxes(table); // Use buildCheckboxes instead of buildSelect
  });
  
  $('#test').on('click', function() {
    table.search('').columns().search('').draw();
    $('#table-wrap').hide();
  });
});

function buildCheckboxes(table) { // Define buildCheckboxes instead of buildSelect
  var counter = 0;
  table.columns([0, 1, 2]).every(function() {
    var column = table.column(this, {
      search: 'applied'
    });
    counter++;
    if (counter === 1) { // Only modify the first column
      var checkboxContainer = $('#dropdown' + counter).empty();
      column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
        var label = $('<label></label>').text(d);
        var checkbox = $('<input type="checkbox" />').val(d);
        label.prepend(checkbox);
        checkboxContainer.append(label);
        checkbox.on('change', function() {
          var selectedValues = checkboxContainer.find('input:checked').map(function() {
            return $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(this).val());
          }).get().join('|');
          column
            .search(selectedValues || '', true, false)
            .draw();
        });
      });
    } else {
      var select = $('<select id="dd' + counter + '"><option value="">Select</option></select>')
        .appendTo($('#dropdown' + counter).empty())
        .on('change', function() {
          var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
            $(this).val()
          );

          column
            .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
            .draw();
        });

      column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
        select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>');
      });

      // The rebuild will clear the existing select, so it needs to be repopulated
      var currSearch = column.search();
      if (currSearch) {
        // Use RegEx to find the selected value from the unique values of the column.
        // This will use the Regular Expression returned from column.search to find the first matching item in column.data().unique
        select.val(column.data().unique().toArray().find((e) => e.match(new RegExp(currSearch))));
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
  </head>
<div class="searchbox" select id="table-filter">
<p><label for="dd1">Name:</label> <span id="dropdown1" input type="checkbox">
  </span>
</p>

<p><label for="dd2">Postion:</label> <span id="dropdown2">
  </span>
</p>

<p><label for="dd3">Office:</label> <span id="dropdown3">
</span>
</p>
  <button type="button"  id="test">Clear Filters</button>
</div>
  <div id="table-wrap">
  <table id="example" class="cell-border row-border stripe dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" role="grid" style=" width: 100%; padding-top: 10px;"><thead>
<tr>

<th>&#160;</th>
<th>&#160;</th>
<th>&#160;</th>
<th colspan="3" style=" text-align: center;">Information</th>
</tr>


          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>ID.AI</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Garrett -2</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ashton.1 -2</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
          </tr>
          
            
          </tr></tbody></table>
</div>
```

Comment: It works great. How can I add some padding between the checkbox entries. In shirt, how can I control the css for checkboxes?

Comment: This is nice, and does what the OP asked for, but again ... a set of checkboxes is the wrong model. You handle it by eliminating the others when one is chosen, but that is the job of _radio buttons_. If you're concerned with the visual, radio buttons can be re-styled to _look_ like checkboxes. Using the wrong model like this harms accessibility (a11y). You and OP may not care about a11y right now, but if you put out a public website or webapp _someone_ will eventually take you to court for being inaccessible. Several disability-rights groups are suing over this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).